# AWS-DynomoDB Two parameter for filter the result using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How can we achieve to get the result from dynomodb using two parameter? I am using below code it's does not work.

```
        var _request = new QueryRequest
        {
            TableName = "Attendence",
            KeyConditionExpression = "Roster_EmpID = :Roster_EmpID and Roster_CreatedDateTime between :v_start and :v_end",
            ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
                {":Roster_EmpID", new AttributeValue {  S = result.empId    }}
                ,{":v_start", new AttributeValue {   S = result.fromDate.ToString(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat)  }}
                ,{":v_end", new AttributeValue { S = result.toDate.ToString(AWSSDKUtils.ISO8601DateFormat)    }}
            },
            IndexName = "Roster_EmpID-index"
        }; 
        var _response = await _client.QueryAsync(_request);
```

But it's not return the result, Please help me to get the result. I already wasted 2 days, still not able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may looking for [`FilterExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TQueryRequest.html)

```
KeyConditionExpression = "Roster_EmpID = :Roster_EmpID ",
FilterExpression = "Roster_CreatedDateTime between :v_start and :v_end",
```

Comment: Yes! but it's not returning the data. Found one more way while creating index method @jaydip. Thanks.